# php implode function styling

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create an online form where user can check desired food from a list and on submit i receive the email to my inbox.

email works fine and i am receiving the data to my email.

My problem is that all the checkboxes checked are received on the same line as below:

**items: Halloumi  |  Pepper Pate  |  Shrimps**

i wish to receive them like this:

- Halloumi
- Pepper Pate
- Shrimps

> ```
> <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="Caviar: black & Red"/>Caviar: black & Red</br>
> <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="Cheese & Ham"/>Cheese & Ham </br>       
> <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="Fetta"/>Fetta </br>
> ```

And Here is my PHP:

> `// CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
> $email_to = "pierreirani@gmail.com";
>
> $email_subject = "Cocktail PassAround";
>
> $items = implode('    |     ',$_POST['items']);
> $qty = implode('    ',$_POST['qty']);
>
> function clean_string($string) {
>   $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
>   return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
> }
>
>
>
> $email_message .= "Items".clean_string($items)."\n";
> $email_message .= "Quantity: ".clean_string($qty)."\n";
>
>
>
>   // create email headers $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();`
>
>   
>   @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);   ?>  
>      Thank you for contacting
>   us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

THank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to send as an ordered list, you need to send the Email as HTML using the proper header information, as stated in the PHP manual for [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Start by replacing:

```
$items = implode('    |     ',$_POST['items']);
```

with:

```
$items = "<ul>"; 
   foreach($_POST['items'] as $item) $items .= "<li>$item</li>";
$items .= "</ul>";
```

then under this line:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

add these two extra lines:

```
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @Fred -ii- this worked perfectally

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$itemString = '<ul>' . "\n";
foreach ($_POST['items'] as $item) {
    $itemString .= '<li>' . $item . '</li>';
}
$itemString = '</ul>' . "\n";
```

and use this new `$itemString` in your message.

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = "<ul>"; 
foreach($_POST['items'] as $item) $items .= "<li>$item</li>"
$items .= "</ul>";
```

Don't forget to send HTML headers in your email if you're going to use markup:

```
Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
```